# How to compile with a runtime identifier inside visual studio

Tags: linux, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am making a .net core app that I presently build/publish to a raspberryPi using this command :

```
dotnet publish -r linux-arm ../MyApp.sln
```

I would like to build and deploy for linux-arm inside visual studio community. (using the start button or <kbd>F5</kbd> button to build for linux-arm)

[image]

For the moment I wrote a bash script with the command above, but it piss me off to trigger the build process from an external script when I could just press F5 inside the IDE.

How to make a build configuration for linux-arm inside visual studio ? Is there a way to modify config to run a specific command line ? Should I use CMake to make my own build config for linux-arm ?

Comment: F5 is equivalent to `dotnet build`, not `dotnet publish`.

Comment: ok then, how to make this "dotnet build" to "dotnet build --linux-arm" ?

Comment: [You can debug .NET Core app using ssh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , yes I know, I already do it.. but to debug with ssh you must deploy your app before. So Yes, I must build in linux-arm before. This is why I build it with linux-arm. Still, it doesn't fix my problem wich is I want to build for linux-arm inside visual sutdio and not with a command line.

Comment: Hello. Do you find any solution ?

Comment: Benoit, With .net5 you don't need to build specifically for linux-arm. Still, you need to deploy then attach the debugger. I didn't find a way to deploy and attach on F5